# Angular 7 - How to include frontend modules and admin modules global assets css/js separately in index.html?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

In my angular project, I have one admin module and rest modules are related to frontend. I have few separate css and js files for admin and frontend, which need to be applied globally. What is the best way to include these assets based on module? One way I know is based on url in javascript:

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('admin')!=-1)
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStylesheet.css" />');
</script>
```

Is this the only way, or there exists a better way of doing this?

Comment: Add your css to `AdminComponent`

Comment: I dont have any common component in admin module, as you said AdminComponent, there are some css/js files added for styling globally in admin module.

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStylesheet.css" *ngIf="window.location.href.includes('admin')"/>`